# C# What is the best way to insert data in to multiple DataTables with the same structure?

Tags: c#

I have 2 datatables with the same column structure:

```
 private static DataTable DTEvents()
        {
            DataTable dtEvents = new DataTable();

            dtEvents.Columns.Add("VIN", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("VehicleName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("Latitude", Type.GetType("System.Double"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("Longitude", Type.GetType("System.Double"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("EventTime", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("EventDuration", Type.GetType("System.TimeSpan"));
            dtEvents.Columns.Add("Speed", Type.GetType("System.Double"));

            return dtEvents;
        }

        DataTable startEvent = DTEvents();
        DataTable endEvent = DTEvents();
```

I then wanted to add a row in to one table or the other,
something like:

```
  DataRow newRow = DTEvents().NewRow();

    //code that fills in newRow goes here

    switch (eventType) //is it a started or ended event?
    {
        case "STARTED":
            dtStartedEvents.ImportRow(newRow);
            break;
        case "ENDED":
            dtEndedEvents.ImportRow(newRow);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

The above doesn't work when I do ImportRow or New.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it throw an error?

Comment: "doesn't work" - means exactly what? Do you get an error?  Nothing happens? App crashes?  Wrong data? etc

Comment: Where are you defining dtStartedEvents and dtEndedEvents?

Comment: I define them on the 2 lines of code that say:
  DataTable startEvent = DTEvents();
   DataTable endEvent = DTEvents();

Comment: Sorry, when i said doesn't work i meant that I get no rows imported in to my new Datatable when I use ImportRow, and when i try to .Add the row called newRow in to my dtStartedEvents or dtEndedEvents I get an error because it is from another DataTable.

Comment: You could condense your question into a simple example, to illustrate where the difficulty lies.
However, each time you call DTEvents() you get a new table. You're making life harder by doing this (and you probably don't dispose of it), so try this...
dtStartedEvents.NewRow() and dtStartedEvents.Add()
Or, if you really must have both, take a reference to the table you want to add a row to, and use that.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BlackLight Thanks for getting back to me, What I was trying to do is use 2 tables, with the same column structure. So yes, i wanted two table objects (dtStartedEvents and dtEndedEvents) and then later on I get a new row that I don't know which table it will go in to, if it is a start event I put it in the startEvent table, if it is an end event, it goes in the endEvent table. I figured the "row" is an object, so I can add it to one table or the other. Anyway, this code is working for my needs now, using my method below. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I ended up doing this, which worked for my needs.

```
 DataRow drNew = dtStartedEvents.NewRow();
 drNew.ItemArray = newRow.ItemArray;
 dtStartedEvents.Rows.Add(drNew);
```